# Add text labels inside the plot area

Tags: r, plot, text, label

[image: graph]

I am having a spaghetti graph and I am trying to make it easier to read.  So far I have managed to have this graph that I group them. Instead of the legend I would like to bring the names of each line inside the plots.

How can I do that? Any ideas?
Thank you!

```
plot<-weekday_unit_grouped%>%
ggplot(aes(x=weekday, y=avg_perc, label=x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=D018_CA, color=D018_CA)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Group)
```

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: You could use `geom_label_repel` from `ggrepel` package. This will add a label at the end of your lines.